# Can't seem to properly generate a delay via timer

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded, timer

So I am trying to create a delay using a timer but doesn't seem like it's working as expected.

With a clock of 16MHz and a prescaler of 1, it should take 10us to reach a count of 160 (unless I did something wrong).

```
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{
    __HAL_RCC_TIM2_CLK_ENABLE();

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 1;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period =  160;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
void Delay() {
    while (1) {
        if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(&htim2, TIM_FLAG_UPDATE))
        {
            GPIOC->ODR ^= GPIO_PIN_10;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Capture:

[image]

Comment: Do you ever clear the flag after it gets set? If not then you're just timing how long your while loop takes to execute.

Comment: are you referring to auto reload register's value being set? doesn't the value reset to 0 after reaching the max count?

Comment: No, I'm referring to the `TIM_FLAG_UPDATE` you're reading with `__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG`. Surely you need to clear that in your code after you see it get set by the timer hardware ... ?

Comment: I see a pulse width of `20us` instead of `10us`

Comment: Are you sure your timer is really getting a 16MHz clock? Is there a divider somewhere you haven't taken to account? What micro are you using?

Comment: When I used a prescaler of 256 and a counter of 65535, I was able to generate the pulse of ~1s long which makes sense. And it's STM32F401RE

Comment: no clue? @brhans

Comment: You're setting `htim2.Init.Prescaler = 1;`, but the actual prescaler used by the timer is "PSC + 1" ([datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00096844-stm32f401xbc-and-stm32f401xde-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) page 368, section 3.4.11).